# PayPal REST API java sdk - custom config file

Tags: java, paypal

Good afternoon all!

I use PayPal REST API java sdk and I want to have different configurations for different environments of my application. Here is how I'm trying to do so:

```
private static boolean IS_PRODUCTION = false;

private static String PAYPAL_ACCESS_TOKEN;

private static void initPayPal() {
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = ApplicationConfig.class.getResourceAsStream(
                IS_PRODUCTION? "/my_paypal_sdk_config.properties" : "/my_paypal_sdk_config_test.properties");
        PayPalResource.initConfig(is);
        String clientID = ConfigManager.getInstance().getConfigurationMap().get("clientID");
        String clientSecret = ConfigManager.getInstance().getConfigurationMap().get("clientSecret");
        PAYPAL_ACCESS_TOKEN = new OAuthTokenCredential(clientID, clientSecret).getAccessToken();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
    }
}
```

and while trying to get the clientID I have

```
java.io.IOException: Resource 'sdk_config.properties' could not be found
```

Strange behavior - I thought I've just configured the sdk to use my own properties file.

Please advice how could I set up those settings properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have made some good improvements to the PayPal Java SDK on integration steps. We are removing the need for sdk_config.properties file as they do not work as well, specially for multi-configuration settings.

Now, all you do is create an `APIContext` instance with `clientId`, `clientSecret`, and `mode`. You pass that context object for any API operation from there on.

Here is how the code would look like for different configurations:

```
APIContext defaultContext = new APIContext(clientId1, clientSecret1, "sandbox");
APIContext sandboxContext = new APIContext(clientId2, clientSecret2, "sandbox");
APIContext someOtherContext = new APIContext(clientId3, clientSecret3, "live");
APIContext liveContext = new APIContext(clientId, clientSecret, "live");

// Now pass any of the above context in these calls, and it would use those configurations.
Payment payment = new Payment();
// Fill in all the details.
payment.create(defaultContext);
// Replace that defaultContext with any of those other contexts.
```

Here is the wiki page explaining that: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/wiki/Making-First-Call

Answer (score 4):

So here is the solution I found:

1. Create an empty sdk_config.properties file in default location
2. Load your own properties:

   ```
   private static void initPayPal() {
       InputStream is = null;
       try {
           is = ApplicationConfig.class.getResourceAsStream(
       IS_PRODUCTION ? "/my_paypal_sdk_config.properties" : "/my_paypal_sdk_config_test.properties");
           Properties props = new Properties();
           props.load(is);
           PayPalResource.initConfig(props);
           ConfigManager.getInstance().load(props);
           String clientID = ConfigManager.getInstance().getConfigurationMap().get("clientID");
           String clientSecret = ConfigManager.getInstance().getConfigurationMap().get("clientSecret");
           PAYPAL_ACCESS_TOKEN = new OAuthTokenCredential(clientID, clientSecret).getAccessToken();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       } finally {
           IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: ConfigManager.load is deprecated. But I also see no other way around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with SDK 0.11 version. I use my own properties file, but code still looked for "sdk_config.properties". I put it into root in my CLASSPATH, but still got the same error. Then I made obvious and horrible solution: put empty "sdk_config.properties" into "rest-api-sdk-0.11.0.jar" library. This street magic solved my problem.